# How to stream netflix on fixed space on screen

Tags: video, video-streaming, netflix

I'm wondering if it's possible through any browsers or software to stream Netflix with a set size, minimal screen space used, but most importantly the "Always on top" functionality.

Currently I just open a new Google Chrome tab and resize it to my needs, but it's not always on top and it takes up more real estate than I'd like it to.

Any suggestions on how to do this?